# How to pack two variables of different type into one object variable?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue

I'm writing multi threaded application.

I need that kind of functionality: one `method#1` puts data into `Queue<>`, and the `method#2` takes this data from the Queue and handles it.

`Method#2` takes 2 arguments: `XElement` and `FileInfo`. How can I store these two variables in `Queue<>` for further usage?

Comment: Any reason you can't create a composite model that you can populate with those two values for a Queue?

Comment: Have you tried tuples?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I thought I can avoid creating new class/struct...

Comment: @Jashaszun what is "tuple" ?

Comment: @Andrew [MSDN on Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `Tuple<XElement, FileInfo>`. Instantiate it like this:

```
Tuple<XElement, FileInfo> tuple = new Tuple<XElement, FileInfo>(elem, file);
```

and then retrieve its values like this:

```
XElement elem = tuple.Item1;
FileInfo file = tuple.Item2;
```

So you can put a `Tuple<XElement, FileInfo>` into your `Queue<Tuple<XElement, FileInfo>>`, and then dequeue the tuples and pass their items to method #2.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that there must be a way to solve my problem without creating new class :)

Comment: @GrantWinney Annoying that you can't use `var` with that syntax because they types can't be inferred.

Comment: @Michael no compiler around to test, but really? I didn't think the compiler would use the return destination to figure out the types. And I don't see why that would be necessary anyhow, considering that you're passing types into the function.

Comment: I'm not downvoting this because this answer is technically correct but it's a really poor way of doing this. `Tuple` makes reading the code a nightmare (everything is `Item1`, `Item2`, ..., especially if it becomes a habit. I used to work on a project where a former team member used tuples for everything - it was near-impossible to understand the code. You really shouldn't do this.

Comment: @Voo Sorry, I misspoke. You can use var, but you can't really enforce the type unless you use `Tuple.Create<T1, T2>(t1, t2)` (i.e. `var test = Tuple.Create("", "")` will create `Tuple<string, string>`, where `var test = Tuple.Create<object, object>("", "") will create `Tuple<object, object>`. You also can't create tuples with nulls using var without specifying T1 and T2)

Comment: @Michael that's true, but in many situations that's not a problem or even preferable. Not necessarily a downside, particularly since the only advantage of this method is that you don't have to explicitly specify the types, if you want to you can still do

Answer (score 3):

You could create a class that has two properties for XElement and FileInfo, then store instances of the class in the Queue.

```
public MyClass {
   public XElement xElement;
   public FileInfo fileInfo;
}
```

Then using it:

```
    Queue<MyClass> queue = new Queue<MyClass>();
    foreach (MyClass instance in queue) {
    Method#2(instance.xElement, instance.fileInfo);
}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than using `Tuple` - the code is more readable this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Queue<(XElement, FileInfo)> data= new Queue<(XElement, FileInfo)>();
```

I'm using this method for my multi threaded data system. Works very well.

Comment: Nice! You should probably mention that this is C# 7 syntax for [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)s.